# CWE-78: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an OS Command ('OS Command Injection')

Tags: java, unix, ssh, java-8, veracode

I am trying to run some SSH commands on server from my application, I am getting CWE-78
Can someone help in mitigating the same
Error:- ***CWE-78: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an OS Command ('OS Command Injection'):
Details: This call to java.lang.Runtime.exec() contains a command injection flaw.  The argument to the function is constructed using untrusted input.  If an attacker is allowed to specify all or part of the command, it may be possible to execute commands on the server with the privileges of the executing process.  The level of exposure depends on the effectiveness of input validation routines, if any. The first argument to exec() contains tainted data from the variable executeCommandsArray. The tainted data originated from an earlier call to AnnotationVirtualController.vc_annotation_entry. Validate all untrusted input to ensure that it conforms to the expected format, using centralized data validation routines when possible.  When using blocklists, be sure that the sanitizing routine performs a sufficient number of iterations to remove all instances of disallowed characters.  Most APIs that execute system commands also have a "safe" version of the method that takes an array of strings as input rather than a single string, which protects against some forms of command injection***

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("cat *" );
             String bashCommand= "/bin/sh";
             String optionCommand = "-c";
             String[] executeCommandsArray= new String[] 
              {bashCommand,optionCommand,sb.toString()};

            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = run.exec(executeCommandsArray);
            int exitcode = pr.waitFor();
```

Comment: A generally more secure approach is not to use SSH at all, but to have an authenticated RPC service on your server that only does the thing it should be doing without unrestricted shell access.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have to use this this is the only way to run few commands

Comment: Firstly you'd be better off using `ProcessBuilder`. Won't necessarily solve the problem but would be an improvement anyway. For one thing, makes it easy to read stderr and stdout with `inheritIO`. Secondly you want to avoid the glob after `cat`. Not only might whatever is scanning your code have flagged that as a problem but if that happens to execute against a binary file, it could play havoc with your terminal response. Try at least to narrow it to specific types of file

Comment: @g00se cat command is just an example I am doing anything its giving me error, even though if I am passing everything as a parameter to exec its giving me sam error

Comment: Tighten it as much as you can and then ignore it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passed string buffer inside the Normalizer it worked

```
      Normalizer.normalize(sb.toString(), Normalizer.Form.NFKD));
```